# How to write MySql Stored Procedures for to show all reason for every vehicle id

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

[image]**i want to show near about 27 reason for every vehicle id,** but my code is show for only for vehicle id 1, below that i want 2,3,4 ....n. **i want to help in nesting of while loop.**
example-i have 27 reasones and 40 vehicles, then for each vehicle 27 resones needs to show. i.e. resulit should be 27x30=810 rows

i am attachicg what my query result show in img

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `searchvehicle`.`reason`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `reason`()
BEGIN
DECLARE vid_t,resnid_t,totkm_t,store_t,pump_t,other_t INT;
DECLARE vnostring_t VARCHAR(30);
DECLARE resn_t VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE indate_t DATE DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE done1 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE m INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE CUR_V CURSOR FOR SELECT vid,vnostring FROM vehicle_owner;
DECLARE CUR_RESN CURSOR FOR SELECT resnid,resn FROM usedfor;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;   
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS allvehicle;
CREATE TABLE allvehicle
 (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  resnid int,
  resn varchar(100),
  vid int,
  vnostring varchar(30),
  indate date,
  totkm int,
  store int,
  pump int,
  other int
  );    
 OPEN CUR_RESN;
 OPEN CUR_V;
 READ_LOOP_R: LOOP      
 READ_LOOP_V:LOOP  
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicle_owner INTO m;
 SET j=0;    
 WHILE j<m DO 
 FETCH CUR_V INTO vid_t,vnostring_t; 
 IF done THEN LEAVE READ_LOOP_V;
 END IF; 
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usedfor INTO n;
 SET i=0;       
 WHILE i<n DO            
 FETCH CUR_RESN INTO resnid_t,resn_t;  
 IF done THEN LEAVE READ_LOOP_R;
 END IF; 
 INSERT INTO allvehicle(vid,vnostring,resnid,resn)values
 (vid_t,vnostring_t,resnid_t,resn_t);    
 SET i = i + 1; 
 END WHILE;          
 SET j = j + 1;           
 END WHILE;      
 END LOOP; 
 END LOOP;     
 CLOSE CUR_RESN;
 CLOSE CUR_V;
 select * from allvehicle;
END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specific join type that forces all rows of one table to be applied to all rows of another table (a "Cartesian product"). This is the CROSS JOIN and it is used like this:

```
select
      r.*, v.*
from reasons r
cross join allvehicles v
```

Note: If you provided sample data and expected result in your question then a more detailed query could be produced.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a855f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
    CREATE TABLE Reasons
    (`id` int)
    ;

    INSERT INTO Reasons
    (`id`)
    VALUES
    (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27)
    ;

    CREATE TABLE allVehicles
    (`vid` int)
    ;

    INSERT INTO allVehicles
    (`vid`)
    VALUES
    (100),(200),(300),(400),(500),(600),(700),(800),(900),(1000)
    ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      r.*, v.*
from reasons r
cross join allvehicles v
order by
    v.vid, r.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a855f/2/0)**:

```
| id |  vid |
|----|------|
|  1 |  100 |
|  2 |  100 |
|  3 |  100 |
|  4 |  100 |
|  5 |  100 |
|  6 |  100 |
|  7 |  100 |
|  8 |  100 |
|  9 |  100 |
| 10 |  100 |
| 11 |  100 |
| 12 |  100 |
| 13 |  100 |
| 14 |  100 |
| 15 |  100 |
| 16 |  100 |
| 17 |  100 |
| 18 |  100 |
| 19 |  100 |
| 20 |  100 |
| 21 |  100 |
| 22 |  100 |
| 23 |  100 |
| 24 |  100 |
| 25 |  100 |
| 26 |  100 |
| 27 |  100 |
|  1 |  200 |
|  2 |  200 |
|  3 |  200 |
|  4 |  200 |
|  5 |  200 |
|  6 |  200 |
|  7 |  200 |
|  8 |  200 |
|  9 |  200 |
| 10 |  200 |
| 11 |  200 |
| 12 |  200 |
| 13 |  200 |
| 14 |  200 |
| 15 |  200 |
| 16 |  200 |
| 17 |  200 |
| 18 |  200 |
| 19 |  200 |
| 20 |  200 |
| 21 |  200 |
| 22 |  200 |
| 23 |  200 |
| 24 |  200 |
| 25 |  200 |
| 26 |  200 |
| 27 |  200 |
|  1 |  300 |
|  2 |  300 |
|  3 |  300 |
|  4 |  300 |
|  5 |  300 |
|  6 |  300 |
|  7 |  300 |
|  8 |  300 |
|  9 |  300 |
| 10 |  300 |
| 11 |  300 |
| 12 |  300 |
| 13 |  300 |
| 14 |  300 |
| 15 |  300 |
| 16 |  300 |
| 17 |  300 |
| 18 |  300 |
| 19 |  300 |
| 20 |  300 |
| 21 |  300 |
| 22 |  300 |
| 23 |  300 |
| 24 |  300 |
| 25 |  300 |
| 26 |  300 |
| 27 |  300 |
|  1 |  400 |
|  2 |  400 |
|  3 |  400 |
|  4 |  400 |
|  5 |  400 |
|  6 |  400 |
|  7 |  400 |
|  8 |  400 |
|  9 |  400 |
| 10 |  400 |
| 11 |  400 |
| 12 |  400 |
| 13 |  400 |
| 14 |  400 |
| 15 |  400 |
| 16 |  400 |
| 17 |  400 |
| 18 |  400 |
| 19 |  400 |
| 20 |  400 |
| 21 |  400 |
| 22 |  400 |
| 23 |  400 |
| 24 |  400 |
| 25 |  400 |
| 26 |  400 |
| 27 |  400 |
|  1 |  500 |
|  2 |  500 |
|  3 |  500 |
|  4 |  500 |
|  5 |  500 |
|  6 |  500 |
|  7 |  500 |
|  8 |  500 |
|  9 |  500 |
| 10 |  500 |
| 11 |  500 |
| 12 |  500 |
| 13 |  500 |
| 14 |  500 |
| 15 |  500 |
| 16 |  500 |
| 17 |  500 |
| 18 |  500 |
| 19 |  500 |
| 20 |  500 |
| 21 |  500 |
| 22 |  500 |
| 23 |  500 |
| 24 |  500 |
| 25 |  500 |
| 26 |  500 |
| 27 |  500 |
|  1 |  600 |
|  2 |  600 |
|  3 |  600 |
|  4 |  600 |
|  5 |  600 |
|  6 |  600 |
|  7 |  600 |
|  8 |  600 |
|  9 |  600 |
| 10 |  600 |
| 11 |  600 |
| 12 |  600 |
| 13 |  600 |
| 14 |  600 |
| 15 |  600 |
| 16 |  600 |
| 17 |  600 |
| 18 |  600 |
| 19 |  600 |
| 20 |  600 |
| 21 |  600 |
| 22 |  600 |
| 23 |  600 |
| 24 |  600 |
| 25 |  600 |
| 26 |  600 |
| 27 |  600 |
|  1 |  700 |
|  2 |  700 |
|  3 |  700 |
|  4 |  700 |
|  5 |  700 |
|  6 |  700 |
|  7 |  700 |
|  8 |  700 |
|  9 |  700 |
| 10 |  700 |
| 11 |  700 |
| 12 |  700 |
| 13 |  700 |
| 14 |  700 |
| 15 |  700 |
| 16 |  700 |
| 17 |  700 |
| 18 |  700 |
| 19 |  700 |
| 20 |  700 |
| 21 |  700 |
| 22 |  700 |
| 23 |  700 |
| 24 |  700 |
| 25 |  700 |
| 26 |  700 |
| 27 |  700 |
|  1 |  800 |
|  2 |  800 |
|  3 |  800 |
|  4 |  800 |
|  5 |  800 |
|  6 |  800 |
|  7 |  800 |
|  8 |  800 |
|  9 |  800 |
| 10 |  800 |
| 11 |  800 |
| 12 |  800 |
| 13 |  800 |
| 14 |  800 |
| 15 |  800 |
| 16 |  800 |
| 17 |  800 |
| 18 |  800 |
| 19 |  800 |
| 20 |  800 |
| 21 |  800 |
| 22 |  800 |
| 23 |  800 |
| 24 |  800 |
| 25 |  800 |
| 26 |  800 |
| 27 |  800 |
|  1 |  900 |
|  2 |  900 |
|  3 |  900 |
|  4 |  900 |
|  5 |  900 |
|  6 |  900 |
|  7 |  900 |
|  8 |  900 |
|  9 |  900 |
| 10 |  900 |
| 11 |  900 |
| 12 |  900 |
| 13 |  900 |
| 14 |  900 |
| 15 |  900 |
| 16 |  900 |
| 17 |  900 |
| 18 |  900 |
| 19 |  900 |
| 20 |  900 |
| 21 |  900 |
| 22 |  900 |
| 23 |  900 |
| 24 |  900 |
| 25 |  900 |
| 26 |  900 |
| 27 |  900 |
|  1 | 1000 |
|  2 | 1000 |
|  3 | 1000 |
|  4 | 1000 |
|  5 | 1000 |
|  6 | 1000 |
|  7 | 1000 |
|  8 | 1000 |
|  9 | 1000 |
| 10 | 1000 |
| 11 | 1000 |
| 12 | 1000 |
| 13 | 1000 |
| 14 | 1000 |
| 15 | 1000 |
| 16 | 1000 |
| 17 | 1000 |
| 18 | 1000 |
| 19 | 1000 |
| 20 | 1000 |
| 21 | 1000 |
| 22 | 1000 |
| 23 | 1000 |
| 24 | 1000 |
| 25 | 1000 |
| 26 | 1000 |
| 27 | 1000 |
```

Comment: sir can you explain it detail.. as ashow in above image of my output, from 28th row should start for vid=20 for same 27 reasones. and so on. means for every vehicle id i want to show these 27 resones..!

Comment: there is no detail needed. all you need is a CROSS JOIN. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a855f/2